# How to "wrap" monadic return value

Tags: haskell, monads

I have the following code:

```
data APNSIdentifier = NoIdentifier | Identifier Word32 deriving (Show, Eq)
newtype APNSItem = Item Put

createNotificationIdentifierItem :: APNSIdentifier -> APNSItem   <--- here
createNotificationIdentifierItem (Identifier identifier) = do
    putWord8 3
    putWord16be 4
    putWord32be identifier
```

How can I "wrap" the `Put` monad with an `APNSItem`? Do I have to make `APNSItem` an instance of the `Monad` typeclass or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Remember that do notation is sugar for >>= and >>. The type signatures there dictate that you'll have to do that *outside* of the do-block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
createNotificationIdentifierItem :: APNSIdentifier -> APNSItem
createNotificationIdentifierItem (Identifier identifier) = Item $ do
    putWord8 3
    putWord16be 4
    putWord32be identifier
```

or

```
createNotificationIdentifierItem :: APNSIdentifier -> APNSItem
createNotificationIdentifierItem (Identifier identifier) = do
    Item $ putWord8 3
    Item $ putWord16be 4
    Item $ putWord32be identifier
```

after making `APNSItem` an instance of `Monad` (you can do this with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, but you'll need to fix `APNSItem` to have a single type variable first)

Comment: How does the second approach work without GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving?

Comment: @Alexander It doesn't.